# How can I select a column with either long or short text, cut the text if length > 100 and add space if < 100 to make it exact 100?

Tags: java, mysql, select

I'm working with an application wherein I need to get a string from database but the string should need to be always 100 in length without using any datatype on the column that I'm retrieving but only a `varchar`? As per my initial sql that I'm working with, I'm going to use a condition in the `SELECT` statement like the below process:

```
SELECT IF (LEN(`name`) >= 100, SUBSTRING(`name`,1,100), //problem) AS formatted_name FROM employee_info;
```

My problem is the else result on the condition, how if it is less than 100 and I want to supply blank spaces to make it 100. For example, name column has only 51 characters therefore I need to supply 49 more blank spaces. Should I control it on the select statement? Does the java process the blank spaces as part of the string that I'm retrieving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`RPAD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad) and [`LPAD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad):

```
SELECT RPAD('str', 5, ' '); -> returns 'str  '
SELECT LPAD('str', 5, ' '); -> returns '  str'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does java recognize those spaces as part of the string or automatically trim it?

Comment: @user3819290 Yes, java returns just what is returned by mysql, without trimming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RPAD` function to pad the spaces, e.g.:

```
SELECT IF (LEN(`name`) >= 100, SUBSTRING(`name`,1,100), RPAD(`name`, 100 -LEN(`name`), ' ')) AS formatted_name 
FROM employee_info;
```

Here's the documentation for [RPAD function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Supposing that mysql returns the string and retrieve it through java, does java trim the blank spaces included?

Comment: Nope, Java doesn't trim the spaces unless you call `trim()` method of `String` class.

Comment: Yes, java trims the blank spaces.

Comment: @priyaraj no, it doesn't. It will return whatever is returned by the query.

Comment: @user3819290 Were you able to get the desired output?